# Android: how to make a "pie Chart" with touchable wedges And the whole thing can rotate

Tags: android, graphics, touch, rotation

I have need to make a sort of "Pie Chart"-style circular display.  the wedges of the chart have to be touchable, and the whole circle has to be able to spin 360deg..

I'm still an android noob, but I'm guessing that I can't do this with a Layout.. right?

preferably, the wedges would be image assets that I create in Photoshop, and not programmaticaly created

does anyone have any Idea where to start with this?

Answer (score 2):

For such an irregular layout, you're going to end up using a `SurfaceView` and drawing the wedges onto a `Canvas`. You'll need to grab the x-y coordinates of touches and work out yourself which wedge has been touched and take appropriate action.

Comment: ok, I had a feeling it was going to be something like that.

thanks for giving me some direction!